# How to fix jquery latest version it always return 1.12.4 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using jquery-rails with latest version
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'

But when i was tried to check which version we used, from browser it return 1.12.4 version,

I want to use latest JQuery version in rails application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'` refers to the gem version, not jQuery version. The jQuery1 latest version is 1.12.4

You can select the jQuery version on `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` by adding one of the following:

`//= require jquery`

`//= require jquery2`

`//= require jquery3`